# Do finite indexes tell us about the finitely generated nature of the related group and subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group and subgroup have a finite index, and we know that the subgroup is finitely generated, can we conclude that the group is also finitely generated?

Comment: Sounds likely.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H=\langle h_1,\ldots, h_n\rangle$ and let $[G:H]=m$.  Suppose $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ is a complete set of coset representatives for $G/H$.  Since,
$$G=\bigcup_{k=1}^m g_kH$$
we can see that $G=\langle\{h_jg_k:1\le j\le n,1\le k\le m\}\rangle$.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to understand. The only typo (unless I am missing something) is that m and n are transposed at the end.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that.  I'll fix it. :)